# google Sheet formula of shift

Tags: google-sheets

I have a cell with today’s date "like cell j11", and I have a "table shifts employee" that contains the numbered beginning of the month to its end, and the table contains data. I want to design a dashboard. If today’s date is equal to the date in the table, it shows me the name of the employees at the time of shift and the data written for the day. I need the formula.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can combine the `=today()` function with a `=vlookup()` against your table to return the correct row of what you are looking for. The formulas are displayed in the image under the relevant cells.

In this example it finds todays date, and looks up the relevant date in the table, and returns the data you want to see into F5 and G5.

[image: Formulas]